# Sumproduct conditional array exclusion

Tags: excel

[Please click for linked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSivP.png)

I'm trying to do a sumifs with an exclusion list, I put together a generic example to help explain.

In this example, I want to add all the animals except elephants and tigers.  Easy to do with a sumproduct:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(D5:D9*(C5:C9=TRANSPOSE(H5:H7)))}
=42
```

Problem is, with my particular file, it's much easier to handle and maintain an exclusion list.  I have 80+ "animals" and I want to exclude around 8, but it's variable enough in specific exclusions and # of exclusions I would prefer to maintain an array, than hard code something in there.

I've tried:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(D5:D9*(C5:C9<>TRANSPOSE(J5:J6)))}

{=SUMPRODUCT(D5:D9*NOT(C5:C9=TRANSPOSE(J5:J6)))}
```

But what I end up getting is
    Giraffes + Lions + Tigers + Rhinos (i.e. NOT Elephants) PLUS Giraffes + Elephants + Lions + Rhinos (i.e. NOT Tigers) = 116

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this approach

`=SUMPRODUCT(D5:D9*ISNA(MATCH(C5:C9,J5:J6,0)))`

You don't need "array entry" for that

If you want an "inclusion list" change `ISNA` to `ISNUMBER`

Comment: Beautiful - I took the match() and the isna(match()) parts and made them arrays to see how it works, that is really simple and clean, thanks!